# big O notation - prove/disprove a logic statement

Tags: time-complexity

I need to prove/disprove the following sentence:
for each f(n)=O(logn) implies 2^(f(n)) = O(n)

I think it's true, because 2^(log(n)) = n.
What do you think?

Comment: This might be a better question for http://cs.stackexchange.com/ or http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/

Comment: belongs on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: What is f(0)? We can create a very nice proof with that.

Comment: what does f(0) matter...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f(n)=O(logn) =>  f(n) <=  Clogn

Therefore, 
     2^(f(n)) <= 2 ^ Clogn
              <=  (2^C) * 2^logn
              <= (2^C) n

So, 2^(f(n) = O(n)
```

[Strictly speaking, you need log<sub>b</sub>x = log<sub>a</sub>x / log<sub>a</sub>b]

Answer (score 1):

f(n) = O(log n) means that there is a positive constant M so that eventually (for all big enough n), we have |f(n)| <= M * log n.

If that's true, then because exponentiation by 2 is an increasing function, we have also that 2^|f(n)| <= 2^M * n.  So the "positive constant" required by the definition is 2^M.

Short answer, yes, but it is not quite as obvious as "it is true because 2^(log n) = n".

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this question including answers will be moved to cs(theory) together:

You can look at the definition of O(...). 
If f(n) = O(log n), that means that there is some constant M such that |f(n)| < M log(n) as n becomes very large. 
If 2^f(n) = O(n), you should be able to find a constant M' such that 2^f(n) < M' n.

Can you do that?